# Recursive function of the product of a list not working

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to create a function that multiplies each item in a list and returns the total. The function doesn't stop running until memory runs out.
Can someone please explain to me why this isn't working?

```
items = [1,2,3,4,10]

def mult2(items):
    if not items:
        return 0
    return mult2(items[0]) * mult2(items[1:])

mult2(items)
```

Comment: Not working as in ... ? 1. Error 2. Wrong Output 3. Exception

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my question. When I call the function with the list and run it, the program will never end, only until memory runs out. It's as if it's not reaching a base case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of mistakes here

1. Your base case is wrong. The Base case has to be when the list is reduced to a single element and you need to return 1 and not 0.
2. You need to send a list with a single element and not the single element alone to meet your base case.

---

Corrected code

```
def mult2(items):
    if len(items)==1:
        return items[0]
    return mult2([items[0]]) * mult2(items[1:])
```

Demo

```
>>> items = [1,2,3,4,10]
>>> 
>>> def mult2(items):
...     if len(items)==1:
...         return items[0]
...     return mult2([items[0]]) * mult2(items[1:])
... 
>>> print(mult2(items))
240
```

Comment: Okay, thanks very much! That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1. Single element is passed to `mult2`, but sequence is expected. That's why `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` is raised, due to trying to subscripting int (code being executed resolves to `1[1:]` which is simply not possible).
2. Your exit condition is broken. Neutral multiplier is 1, not 0.

After fixes your code would look like this:

```
def mult2(seq):
    if not seq:
        return 1
    return seq[0] * mult2(seq[1:])

items = [1,2,3,4,10]
assert 240 == mult2(items)
```

Comment: best answer for realizing you dont need to recursively call on the first item

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a base case for your recursion that works properly.

Consider calling `mult2` with `[1,2,3]` this gets to the return statement which called `mult2` with `1` and with `[1,2]`.

The problem is in the call to `mult2` with the parameter `1` which is just an integer. When you get to the recursive part there's no indexing available because `items` is just an int at this point, so `items[0]` and `items[1:]` don't make sense at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the errors in the OP, and this works:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,10]

def mult2(items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        return items[0]
    return items[0] * mult2(items[1:])

print "sum:",mult2(items)
```