# How should I write a recursive function that returns multiple values?

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I want the output to be a tuple including the sum the the product.
For example the list [1,2,3,4] should output (10,24). I can get the sum and product individually but cannot get both at the same time. Here's what I have so far:

```
def sum_product(aList):
    if len(aList) == 1:
        return aList[0]
    result = sum_product(aList[1:])
    return (result + aList[0], result*aList[0])

sum_product([1,2,3,4])
```

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why would you want to use recursion here? Is this a homework question that explicitly mandates a recursive function? In any other case, you can achieve this much easier with iteration

Comment: Think carefully about what you should return in the base case. In particular, you still need to return a sum *and* a product separately, right? Then think carefully about the recursion: what kind of value will you get back when you make the recursive call? What should you do with that result in order to get the "subtotal" that you use for the local sum calculation? And for the product calculation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function of the product of a list not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943301/recursive-function-of-the-product-of-a-list-not-working)

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder no, that does not address the issues with OP's code.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question because the intention is plain and the OP demonstrates a clear attempt with the posted code. The closing reason _"not reproducible or was caused by typos"_ does not fit at all. This is a new user and slamming the door on their question is harmful. Please re-open this.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was that you return different types. In the end of recursion you return int, but in general return a tuple. I changed your code, so now it works.

```py
def sum_product(aList):
    if len(aList) == 1:
        return aList[0], aList[0] #list[0] for sum and list[0] for product
    result = sum_product(aList[1:])
    return (result[0] + aList[0], result[1] * aList[0])
```